# check if menuitem was selected; pygtk

Tags: pygtk, ubuntu-unity

maybe a trivial question, but I'm having some severe problems with PyGTK...
I'm trying to programm an application indicator for unity with gtk, and I'm trying to set some  of my menuitems insensitive (via `set_sensitive(False)`) after I clicked on them...

Here's a code snippet:

```
class CheckNAS: 
    def __init__(self): 
      self.ind = appindicator.Indicator("debian-doc-menu", "indicator-   messages",appindicator.CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS)
      self.ind.set_status (appindicator.STATUS_ACTIVE)
      self.ind.set_attention_icon("icon1")
      self.ind.set_icon("icon2")

    def menu_setup(self):
      self.quit_item = gtk.MenuItem("QUIT") 
      self.quit_item.connect("activate",self.quit)

      if condition_function()==True:
        self.quit.set_sensitive(False)
      self.quit_item.show()
      self.menu.append(self.quit_item)
```

and then I do repeatedly `menu_setup` via an `add_timeout(1000,self.condition_function)`. This works fine in principle, but I'd prefer that the menuitem turns insensitive immiediately after I clicked it...
Sorry for the Noob-question:)

Comment: You have a typo in `self.quit.set_sensitive(False)`, should be `self.quit_item.set_sensitive(False)`. Is that the problem?

Comment: no unfortunately not, this is just due to the fact, that I rearranged the code a little bit

Comment: Can you supply a minimal code that produces the problem and can be run? You should be able to just run `set_sensitive(False)` and have it stay, I've done so myself in an app without problem. So your problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is that what you want?

```
class CheckNAS: 
    def __init__(self): 
      self.ind = appindicator.Indicator("debian-doc-menu", 
        "indicator-messages",appindicator.CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS)
      self.ind.set_status (appindicator.STATUS_ACTIVE)
      self.ind.set_attention_icon("icon1")
      self.ind.set_icon("icon2")

    def menu_setup(self):
      self.quit_item = gtk.MenuItem("QUIT") 
      self.quit_item.connect("activate",self.sensitive)
      self.quit_item.show()
      self.menu.append(self.quit_item)

    def sensitive(self,widget):
      if widget.get_sensitive():
        widget.set_sensitive(False)
      else:
        widget.set_sensitive(True)
```

Comment: yes thanks! that was exactly I was looking for. I didn't realize that I can work with the widgets as parameters for functions. I'm still learning

Comment: is it possible to run to connect one after another. In other words to make the button insensitive for let's say 5 seconds, and then make it sensitive again?

Comment: there is no need to connect the object to a second signal. Just do everything within the `sensitive` function. You can for example import the `time` module (`import time` in the first lines of your file and `time.sleep(5)` in the `sensitive` function (`widget.set_sensitive(False) \ time.sleep(5) \ widget.set_sensitive(True)`))